# when running selenium Edge in pyton- getting "sedgedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm runing a python code in Edge selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Service(executable_path=EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(login_url)
driver.maximize_window()
sleep_val = random.randint(0, 2)
time.sleep(sleep_val)
driver.get(check_url)
sleep_val = random.randint(0, 3)
time.sleep(sleep_val)
print("user id is:        " + user_name)
print("user pass is:        " + password)
```

after upgrading selenium version and python version to 3.10 , I'm getting an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\XXXt\.wdm\drivers\edgedriver\win64\103.0.1264.37\msedgedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

any solution?

Comment: I found that `.wdm` exists in the file path of the driver, is it possible that there is an escaping error? Do you have the same problem when you haven't upgraded Selenium yet?

Comment: No, didn't had this error

Answer (score 1):

There are various issues for chromium drivers for browser v103 used by Edge and Google Chrome. These are being addressed in v104, but they are still in beta.

Advise that you downgrade for now to v102.

See problem links here:
[Bug in either Webdriver 103.*.* or Edge 103.*.* - unexpected command response](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/EdgeWebDriver/issues/21)
[Issue 4121: WebDriver command sometimes fails with "unexpected command response"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4121)
[[ Bug]: Error using user-data-dir= in Chrome 103.0.5060.53](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10799)
[ChromeDriver issue with Chrome v103 last night.](https://zhiminzhan.medium.com/resolve-chromedriver-issues-in-web-test-automation-e64af01dfda3)