# getting this error "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: angular is not defined"

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error and i am not getting any solutions. I have chosen the proper root selector and model. I believe i have added all the required dependencies. I am trying to automate a testcase with angular.

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: angular is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-UPVJF2U', ip: '192.168.0.132', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [7c6f180eaae1b4997e8c2c08aa4bc0ed, executeScript {script=var using = arguments[0] || document;
var rootSelector = '"app-create-customers"';
var model = 'state';

var getNg1Hooks = function(selector, injectorPlease) {
  function tryEl(el) {
    try {
      if (!injectorPlease && angular.getTestability) {
        var $$testability = angular.getTestability(el);
        if ($$testability) {
          return {$$testability: $$testability};
        }
      } else {
        var $injector = angular.element(el).injector();
        if ($injector) {
          return {$injector: $injector};
        }
      }
    } catch(err) {}
  }
  function trySelector(selector) {
    var els = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
      var elHooks = tryEl(els[i]);
      if (elHooks) {
        return elHooks;
      }
    }
  }

  if (selector) {
    return trySelector(selector);
  } else if (window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__) {
    var $injector = window.__TESTABILITY__NG1_APP_ROOT_INJECTOR__;
    var $$testability = null;
    try {
      $$testability = $injector.get('$$testability');
    } catch (e) {}
    return {$injector: $injector, $$testability: $$testability};
  } else {
    return tryEl(document.body) ||
        trySelector('[ng-app]') || trySelector('[ng\\:app]') ||
        trySelector('[ng-controller]') || trySelector('[ng\\:controller]');
  }
}

  using = using || document;

  if (angular.getTestability) {
    return getNg1Hooks(rootSelector).$$testability.
        findModels(using, model, true);
  }
  var prefixes = ['ng-', 'ng_', 'data-ng-', 'x-ng-', 'ng\\:'];
  for (var p = 0; p < prefixes.length; ++p) {
    var selector = '[' + prefixes[p] + 'model="' + model + '"]';
    var elements = using.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if (elements.length) {
      return elements;
    }
  }
, args=[null]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 103.0.5060.114, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd7..., userDataDir: C:\Users\win10\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56971}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:56971/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.114, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 7c6f180eaae1b4997e8c2c08aa4bc0ed
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:588)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:522)
    at com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.ByAngularModel.getObject(ByAngularModel.java:43)
    at com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.ByAngular$BaseBy.findElement(ByAngular.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$1.findElement(ElementLocation.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:406)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:398)
    at com.vilcart.app.ReadLogin.ReadData(ReadLogin.java:136)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
... Removed 28 stack frames
```

...............................................................
My Code is

```
...
WebElement stateSelect = driver.findElement(ByAngular.withRootSelector("\"app-create-customers\"").model("state"));
...
```

---

My Html doc in angular app looks like so.

```
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userinput4">State<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                <ng-select [(ngModel)]="state" (change)="onSelectState()">
                  <ng-option value="KARNATAKA">KARNATAKA</ng-option>
                  <ng-option value="TAMIL NADU">TAMIL NADU</ng-option>
                  <ng-option value="ANDHRA PRADESH">ANDHRA PRADESH</ng-option>
                </ng-select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

---

My angular app selector is
...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-customers',
  templateUrl: './create-customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-customers.component.css']
})
```

### ...

On inspecting the web element

```
<app-create-customers _nghost-eqi-c178="" class="ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-eqi-c178="" class="app-content content">...
```

---

Comment: Just use Java.  Right now you're mixing Java and Javascript and that's the long way to Tipperary.    The error means there's nothing defined as "angular".  (You may need to include that in each executescript command... Angular framework defines?)  There's no need to use Angular to test Angular.  You want to come in as the user does... through the interface.

Comment: Thank you pcalkins for your response,i am not using javascript, The error is dumping javascript code. I am using java, The code i pasted in typescript is about the angular app. My code entirety is this.                                                                        "WebElement stateSelect = driver.findElement(ByAngular.withRootSelector("\"app-create-customers\"").model("state"));"

Comment: seems your "ByAngular" custom function is using javascript.

Comment: You are using version 103 of chromium, there have been many issues with the chromium drivers (Google, Edge..). Suggest you downgrade to v102 or try the v104 that is in beta (chrome driver already available). See here for issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72852012/11543023

Comment: I tried in firefox, chrome v102 & v104 i am yet getting the same issue.