# Unhandled exception has occured in your application. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to `driver.navigate()` with C# selenium. This code works fine at some people.

[image: here is the error]

Chromedriver version: 103.0.5060.53

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();

Thread.Sleep(500);

process.StandardInput.WriteLine(label28.Text);
process.StandardInput.Flush();
process.StandardInput.Close();

ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:9222";

driver = new ChromeDriver(service, option);

Thread.Sleep(3000);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
```

Comment: Do note that that screenshot gives no useful information. It only says "something crashed". The "Details" button should give some more information, sometimes unhandled exceptions are logged also in the windows event viewer. Anyway the code should do a proper exception handling and if/when exceptions are raised act on them (for example logging the error information so you or others can give support to them)

Comment: "Details" button is there for a reason.

Comment: sorry for bad quality here is the details https://prnt.sc/LXEzo6S4lANO

Comment: don't feel sorry for the bad quality, don't make a photo in the first place. Copy and paste the actual text, and provide it here. Microsoft, in their wisdom, made the details area a textbox for people to select the text and copy it. notice, you should answer to comments with @username for the user to get notified about the answer.

Comment: Which version of Google Chrome do you have? Chrome likes to auto-update itself.

Comment: You are using version 103 of chromium, there have been many issues with the chromium drivers (Google, Edge..). Suggest you downgrade to v102 or try the v104 that is in beta (chrome driver already available). See here for issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72852012/11543023